# Image not loading - how to fix?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am viewing an image from url [http://arabian-chemistry.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/إدارة-التغير.png](http://arabian-chemistry.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/%D8%A7%D9%95%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D8%BA%D9%8A%D8%B1.png)
and this is my code to fetch the image

```
RequestQueue mQueue = newRequestQueue(context);
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(mQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {

        }
    });
 img.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader);
```

the above code is working fine on lollipop devices and higher but it doesn't load on kitkat and older versions of android and give this error in the log

```
02-21 14:49:42.072 28684-29279/com.alpha25.wordpressapp E/Volley: [6654] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 301 for http://arabian-chemistry.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/إدارة-التغير.png
```

I think this problem is because of SSLHandshakeException so I searched for a solution but I don't know how to use with my code
this is code that I found

```
SSLContext sslContext = null;
        try {
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, null, null);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SSLSocketFactory noSSLv3Factory = null;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            try {
                noSSLv3Factory = new NoSSLv3SocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
            } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            noSSLv3Factory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        }

        OkHttpClient.Builder okb = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .sslSocketFactory(noSSLv3Factory, provideX509TrustManager());
        OkHttpClient ok = okb.build();
```

please any suggestion to correct this

Comment: are you having trouble to display that image inside an imageview ?

Comment: Yes, I am using networkImageView .. the image is not viewed and also the image url is not opening in the device browser .. my device is kitkat 4.4.4

Answer (score 0):

try this url

```
https://arabian-chemistry.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/إدارة-التغير.png
```

or if you don't want to use this solution you can go with glide or picasso to load images they are internally handling this by default.

hope this will help you.

Comment: try with https:

Answer (score 0):

Try [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) which is simple library for fetching images from internet to your views.

Example use:

```
// For a simple view:
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

  GlideApp.with(this).load("http://YOURDOMAIN.COM").into(imageView);
}

// For a simple image list:
@Override public View getView(int position, View recycled, ViewGroup container) {
  final ImageView myImageView;
  if (recycled == null) {
    myImageView = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_image_view, container, false);
  } else {
    myImageView = (ImageView) recycled;
  }

  String url = myUrls.get(position);

  GlideApp
    .with(myFragment)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .into(myImageView);

  return myImageView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to load an image without arabic latters?
Also the 301 mean that the server is fowarding you, so you might specify a refer url and a user agent, spoofing urself as a browser

Comment: I encoded the url and it is not opened even on the device browser

Answer (score 0):

First Advice : Use another library that support `followRedirection`
but if you insist on using Volley add bellow code on `onError` function

```
 @Override
public void deliverError(final VolleyError error) {
Log.d(TAG, "deliverError");

final int status = error.networkResponse.statusCode;
// Handle 30x 
if(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM == status || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER) {
    final String location = error.networkResponse.headers.get("Location");
    Log.d(TAG, "Location: " + location);
    final GsonRequest<T> request = new GsonRequest<T>(method, location, jsonRequest, this.requestContentType, this.clazz, this.ttl, this.listener, this.errorListener);
    // Construct a request clone and change the url to redirect location.
    RequestManager.getRequestQueue().add(request);
}
}
```

this code follows requests that redirect with `301` response code. request